# How to add a jquery function to a google custom search form on submit

Tags: jquery, search

It would be great to bind a jquery function to a 'google custom search' form on my website to see what visitors are searching. The following code works, however, I would like some help to find the search string on submitting the form. I tried `$('form').submit(function(){` but did not work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search').focusout(function(){
       var searchstring = $('form').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').val();
       console.log("search string: "+searchstring);  
    });

}); //enddocready
```

html below

```
<div id="search">
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'uniquecode123467';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = false;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

Comment: #search is my div which contains the google search form

Comment: can you paste yout html along with all jquery library you used ? although i think it's not possible